# resume template and small caps

Tags: templates, cv, resume

**UPDATE**

My MWE is,

```
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6} % Link color
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour,linkcolor=linkcolour} 
\name{My name, P\textsc{h}.D}

\begin{document}
\begin{rSection}{Personal Data}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
\textsc{Address:} &  something. \\
\textsc{Temporary Address:} &   something, Luxembourg \\
\textsc{Phone:}&   111111 \\
\textsc{email:}&  \href{mailto:at@gmail.com}{at@gmail.com}\\
\textsc{Languages:}&  something\\
\end{tabular}

\end{rSection}

\end{document}
```

My problem is that when I compile, "my name" appears with capital letters which is OK, but what I particularly do not like and want to fix is that the letter "h", in the title Ph.D, appears with capital letter as well - although, I used the `\texsc{}` command.

Can some help me with to account for small caps inside the `\name{}` command line?

The file resume.cls for the resume style can be found [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/res?lang=en)

Here it is the result

[image]

Comment: Welcome, please link to the used version of `resume`?

Comment: The class is named `res.cls` if you link to https://www.ctan.org/pkg/res?lang=en -- and the document produces **nothing** so far

Comment: This time, just this time, you can try `P{\sc h}.D`.

Comment: @Johannes_B: `\scshape`

Comment: @Johannes_B is [https://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/res.cls] what you need or my own file ?

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the suggested solutions worked.

Answer (score 3):

*Dirty templates, dirty solutions.*

Use the following, which is ugly, but ...

```
\name{My name, P\MakeLowercase{h}.D}
```

If you use a font that supports bold small caps, you can do that as well.

[image: mshResume]

By the way, the code is from either https://github.com/treyhunner/resume
or http://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-professional-cv

Comment: Sorry, this looks awful!!!!

Comment: @msh855: If you use this style of Ph.D. your PhD degree should be revoked ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, so far this is my lucky template, though - lot of interviews and already a job offer ! :)   ... but, I am willing to hear another suggestion for template.

Comment: Well, I am not your employer

Comment: @msh855 I think this is more because of the content, i.e. what you are able to do. Not solely about the looks ;-)